# Maven Dependency Management is importing wrong version

Tags: maven, plugins, camunda

I am cloning project to import a 7.13 version dependency as depicted here. As you can see, the `camunda-webapp: 7.11.0` (managed from 7.13.0) is creeping in. This is causing some ClassNotFoundExceptions since I need `camunda-webapp: 7.13.0` which IS happening correctly in a diff project I dont own. I did a lot of digging and exclusions but I'm not able to figure out where is this whole `7.11.0 (managed from 7.13.0)` is even coming from.

*How can i force this project to use `7.13.0` throughout?*

[image]

However, In another project importing 7.13  imports the transitive 7.13 correctly.

[image]

EDIT - Updating the POM here to triage the fix:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.getstarted</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-ctil-cockpit</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <camunda.spring-boot.version>7.13.0</camunda.spring-boot.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.3.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <capitalone.camunda.plugin.version>1.5</capitalone.camunda.plugin.version>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${capitalone.camunda.plugin.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  </dependencyManagement>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${camunda.spring-boot.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.webapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-webapp-webjar</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
      <version>${camunda.spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>capitalone-uioverlay</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.webapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-webapp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>custom-engine-types</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.webapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-webapp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>common-cockpit-extensions</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.webapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-webapp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.identity</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-identity-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <layout>ZIP</layout>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
     <finalName>camunda-ctil-cockpit</finalName>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

However this results still in. As you can see 7.11 is still there. If I exclude 7.11 completely, the `camunda-webapp.jar` completely disappears. Was hoping 7.13 would get popped in. Also `camunda-webapp-webjar` is completely removed, comparing to the screenshots above :
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the actual XML?

Comment: added the original POM

Comment: It looks like the version is coming from `<dependencyManagement>`, i.e. from one of the entries with scope `import`.

Answer (score 1):

First change the  property value of

```
<camunda.spring-boot.version>3.2.0</camunda.spring-boot.version>
```

to **7.13.0**
See e.g. https://start.camunda.com/

If the issue persists the the plugin jars define their own versions, not driven by the BOM:

You shared the main project POM including the engine and webapps, but the unwanted dependency is coming in as a dependency of your custom com.capitalone.* jars, as the screenshot of the dependency tree shows. camunda-webapp:7.11.0 is a dependency which is pulled in by

```
1)
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>capitalone-uioverlay</artifactId>
    </dependency>
2)  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>custom-engine-types</artifactId>
    </dependency>
3)
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.capitalone.camunda.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>common-cockpit-extensions</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

A) If possible update the POMs of those projects and run a mvn clean install on them

B) If you have no control over these projects then you can also add exclusions to the dependency tags listed above (as the jar is already included in the main project). However, this would mean your plugin jars running with another jar version than they have been compiled against. It is not a good practice and may cause issue if compatibility changed.

On a different note:
"Please note that we updated the frontend plugin interface with Camunda Platform Runtime 7.14. Plugins written for Camunda Platform Runtime 7.13 and earlier might no longer work with Camunda Platform Runtime 7.14. Checkout the update guide for more details." https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/webapps/cockpit/extend/plugins/

Comment: Added another remark in the beginning. In case the plugins inherit the BOM, its version would affect them. Whoever did: It would be nice to comment. A silent silent  downvote does not contribute to a solution, which is definitely in the area of my answer

Comment: updated the Pom based on the above suggestions(Added an EDIT for the new changes). I dont own the indicated dependencies so I issued an exclusion to the  <artifactId>camunda-webapp</artifactId>. (I've updated the original POM for easier reading. However  camunda-webapp 7.11  still shows up under the camunda -bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp.core (I've pushed screenshots and udpated POM in the bottom of the main thread) AND camunda-webapp-webjar disappeared as indicated in the updates screenshots. I need someway to force camunda webapp AND camunda-webapp-webjar 7.13 to appear as intended

Comment: Please run a: mvn dependency:tree on the command line in the folder of the POM and share the result (can replace the screenshots)